# View response data from AJAX request for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a *like system* in my website. Each message has a Like button and a counter next to it.
Now when someone clicks the Like button it should immediately change to 1, and if another user clicks the same message it would change to 2 and so on for each individual message.

I created the AJAX functions required to do this, but I am using `document.getElementById` which only retrieves the first instance found and views the response from the ajax request.

How can I make it so that it is viewed for each individual message?

Here is my AJAX requests:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.msg-icon').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
 
    var reply_id = $(this).find('input[name="replymsg"]').val();
   var request = reply(reply_id); 
   
    request.done(function() { 
      checkLikes(reply_id);
    });
  });
});
   
  
function reply(reply_id) {
  return $.ajax({ 
    data: reply_id, 
    type: "post", 
    url: "replyfavorite.php?replymsg="+reply_id, 
  });
}

function checkLikes(reply_id) {
  return $.ajax({
    data: { reply: reply_id },
    type: "get",
    url: "checkLikes.php?reply=" + reply_id,
    success: function(data) {
      document.getElementById('likesCount').innerHTML = data; //what can i change here to make the data go to each clicked button?
    }
  });
}
```

here is my html button that users click for each message:

```
<a href="" class="msg-icon" >

<i class="fas fa-heart fa-lg" id="favBtn" style="color: #e74f4e !important;"  >
  <span id="likesCount"><?php echo $row3['likes_count'] ?>
</span></i></a>
```

the code is working fine my only problem is with how to let the response go to the clicked message button only.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan its a typo in the question...........

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan you have any solution regarding my question please?

Comment: I'm just making sure the issue are not missing closing tags. (When asking questions make sure to create a [mcve] - don't leave details out - or you'll receive sub-comments instead of detailed answers.)

Comment: You have this piece of code: `$(this).find('input[name="replymsg"]').val()` Can you explain it?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i didnt leave anything out... i already said the code is working fine, and explained exactly where my issue is. please provide an answer and dont divert my question elsewhere

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan it finds the input which name is replymsg and retrieves its value. why do u want me to explain ?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan any answers please? you commented and asked irrelevant things. please contribute to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noticed, ***ID* should be unique**. Instead of using `document.getElementById('likesCount').innerHTML = data;`
use the [**`data-*` attribute**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

I.e:

```
<span data-id="536">12</span>
```

than inside the jQuery `success` do like:

```
success: function(data) {
  $(`[data-id="${reply_id}"]`).text(data)
}
```

and such will update any number of `data-id=""` elements on the page with the newest *likes count*.

***PS:*** if you want to make your *counts* ***"live"*** - instead of using AJAX  which is one roundtrip-only (request → response), you could use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

By using Web Sockets you're making sure an initial handshake is made between any client and your server and than small packets are shared between the two - for multiple clients simultaneously. That way you don't need to have recurring AJAX intervals - and all your guests will see the likes change value *"automagically"*.

Comment: thank you, amazing answer. this will help me in future areas of my project

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using jquery, why not use $("#likesCount").each(function(){ . . . . .. }); to loop through each item, an inside the each portion you do your ajax request to look for the current value, maybe using $.post() or $.get(), depending on your api.

Update: (Improving my answer)
I understand about the uniqueness of the id of an element in a document.

What I really wanted to say is that you may want change the approach on how to look/search for the details to include inside each span. There you can identify the span objects by grouping them using a Class or a custom attribute, then iterate them using the $.each function. There is no single way to accomplish things, this is just an idea on how to update each element with the correct content.

Comment: in no way does this answer my question.

Comment: You're suggesting to: *`why not use $("#likesCount").each(`*. Julio, `#likesCount` is and ID selector, and there's no need to `each`, since inside a page there can only be **one** single ID element. Also since in jQuery a selector wrapped inside a jQuery object - jQuery provides many methods which internally (within the library) already operate using the `.each` Just for example, say you have many `.foo` elements: `$(".foo").text("BAR")` will change the text of all those elements - without the need to for-each every single one (like we need to do in pure JS)